# karate - How to set specific values in a feature file which is called internally

Tags: karate

This is my framework structure currently

```
CreateDiscount.feature
Discount_Payload.json
SearchDiscount.feature
Search_Payload.json
```

This is how the code in each file looks
    CreateDiscount.feature

```
Scenario: Create a discount
* def changes = read('Discount_Payload.json')
* set changes.code = cu.getCouponCode(4)
* set changes.operator = 'LT'
Given url baseUrl + CREATE_DISCOUNT
And request changes
When method post
Then status 200
```

Discount_Payload.json

```
{
"code": "ND12", 
"name": "NDS coupon Testing",
"description": "NDS coupon testing via postman",
"operator": "EQ"
}
```

SearchDiscount.feature

```
Scenario: Create a discount and search it
* def createDiscount = call read('CreateDiscount.feature') 
* print createDiscount
* def coupon_code = createDiscount.changes.code
* print coupon_code
* def changes = read('Search_Payload.json')
* set changes.coupon_code = coupon_code
Given url baseUrl + SEARCH
And request changes
When method post
Then status 200

Search_Payload.json
{
 "mode" : "Browse",
 "coupon_code" : "abrakadabra"
}
```

So currently whenever I run SearchDiscount.feature , It internally calls CreateDiscount.feature , This is fine if I have only **code** and **operator** values to be set while creating discount.

But now when I want to run separate test case in SearchDiscount.feature
for which I want to update the value of **name** and **description** of Discount_Payload.json also from SearchDiscount.feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass values to feature file that you are calling

Instead of reading a json in you feature which you want to reuse, pass that json in a variable as an input to your feature.

SearchDiscount.feature

```
* def discountInput = read('Discount_Payload.json')
* def createDiscount = call read('CreateDiscount.feature' ) {'changes' :'#(discountInput)'}
```

Now you don't need to read for input in your CreateDiscount.feature

Delete

```
 * def changes = read('Discount_Payload.json')
```

from your CreateDiscount.feature

you can change whatever values you want in your calling feature before passing it to your reusable feature.

**EDIT**: If you want to run this for different values you can use scenario outline and set values to your discountInput before passing it to your feature.

please refer karate documentation.

https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

**EDIT 2:**
Scenario Outline sample for your question.

```
Scenario Outline:
    * def discountInput = read('Discount_Payload.json')
    * set discountInput.name = <name>
    * set discountInput.description = <description>
    * def createDiscount = call read('CreateDiscount.feature' ) {'changes' :'#(discountInput)'}
Examples:
    |   name  |   description  |
    |   'A'   |      'Ades'    |
    |   'B'   |      'Bdes'    |
```

now the scenario will run with these 2 set of values provided in the examples.

Comment: How will I pass different "name" and "operator" at runtime while calling it from SearchDiscount.feature.

Comment: You can use scenario Outline, create Examples with different name and operator values. and set those values to your json before passing

Comment: Thanks Babu , Can you please elaborate on it , may be sample code or link to already implemented example ?

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-netty/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/mock/hello-data-driven.feature

Comment: Above two links are having good examples for using scenario outline

Comment: Scenario: Positive - Create a discount and search it

* def discountInput = read('Discount_Payload.json')
* set discountInput.code = cu.getCouponCode(4)
* def createDiscount = call read('CreateDiscount.feature' ) {'changes' :'#(discountInput)'}
Given url baseUrl + CREATE_DISCOUNT
And request changes
When method post
Then status 400

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand your question just by this code. Can you provide more details to understand the issue.

Comment: I did not understand {'changes' :'#(discountInput)'} this part in the code you suggested

Comment: Those are embedded js expressions to assign value for key in your json. https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

Comment: @sourabh i have added an example for scenario outline as well. please refer EDIT 2 section in my answer

Comment: Scenario: Positive - Create a discount and search it

* def discountInput = read('Discount_Payload.json')
* set discountInput.discount_type = 'PROMOTION'
* def createDiscount = call read('CreateDiscount.feature' ) discountInput
* def coupon_code = createDiscount.code
* def changes = read('Search_Payload.json')
* set changes.coupon_code = coupon_code
Given url baseUrl + SEARCH
And request changes
When method post
Then status 200

Comment: * def createDiscount = call read('CreateDiscount.feature' ) discountInput .... If you pass input like this you might have to change your createDiscount.feature. Try as it as my answer given above so that you can access the variable "changes" in your feature