# KARATE - How to get data from response/by running another feature file

Tags: karate

I have a feature file that connects to oracle database and gets data and prints in response. Below's the sample piece of code.

**dbconnect.feature**

```
def queryDATA = 'QueryData' 
When def db = DBConnect.queryDB(host, port, serviceName, username, password, queryDATA)
Then print db
```

***Note that I have a few more lines of code before this which sets up jdbc and connects to DB with proper credentials

Post this, I need to run real test case which inturn should call **dbconnect.feature** to get DATA and feed to request. It goes like this;

**UserDetails.feature**

```
Background: 
* url 'https://soaheader-env-name.com'
* header agent_uid = 'AUTO_TST'
* configure ssl = true
* header Authorization = call read('classpath:ABC/JSFiles/auth.js') { 
username: 'XYZ', password: '123' }
* configure logPrettyResponse = true
* configure logPrettyRequest = true

@UserDetails
Scenario Outline: Get User Details
Given path 'somefooterurl/account/<accountno>/user-details-summary'
When method get
Then status 200
Then match response contains 'OK'
```

I really need to use the data from **dbconnect.feature** and provide in **UserDetails.feature** request.

Please suggest a way/ help me with the proper path in karate-github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example for you,

```
* def dbCall = call read('dbconnect.feature')
* def db = dbCall.db
```

please refer [karate documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files)

Other references if you want to pass values to your feature:

[Properly calling an authorization Karate feature with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725546/properly-calling-an-authorization-karate-feature-with-arguments)

[karate - How to set specific values in a feature file which is called internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52660690/karate-how-to-set-specific-values-in-a-feature-file-which-is-called-internally)