# calling A.feature from B.feature is returning com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@xxxxxx

Tags: karate

I apologize if this has been answered in a previous thread, I tried searching and was not able to find any that were this specific problem.

I am trying to call A.feature from B.Feature - where A returns a specific value to be used in B

A.feature:

```
    Given url endpoint
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json,text/plain'
    And request
    """
    {
        "prod": "xxxx"
    }
    """
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then match response[0].acc.insType == 'xxx'
    And def accKey = response[0].account.accKey
```

then in B.feature, i am calling it with the `* call read`:

`* def key = call read('ReadRoundUpSubscription.feature');`

`* print 'Account Key is ' + key`

But it is returning
`[print] Account Key is com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@xxxxxx`

UPDATE:

I changed this line:
`And def accKey = response[0].account.accKey`
to be
`And set accKey = response[0].account.accKey`

and now i am getting `variable is null or not set 'accountToken'`

Update 2:

I figured it out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855334/karate-how-to-get-data-from-response-by-running-another-feature-file) post
A.feature ends with
`* def accKey = response[0].account.accKey`

Then in B.feature:
`* def key = karate.call('ReadRoundUpSubscription.feature');`

`* def keyvalue = key.acckey`

I realize my variable names are bad. real bad.

If there is a better way to accomplish this result please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you finally got it: `* def keyvalue = key.acckey` - so the result will contain an envelope of all variables in the "called" feature.

This is explained in detail in the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-other-feature-files