# get the params value from a variable

Tags: api, parameters, karate

i have one feature file as
Feature: Getting the Token

Background:

header Content-Type 'application/json'

- def CookieGenerator = Java.type('com.ade.Helpers.CookiesGenerator');

def endpoints read('classpath: src/test/java/com/ade/resources/endpoints.json')

Given url endpoints.token

Scenario: To check the Schema of the response

Given cookies (new CookieGenerator().getCookieValue())

When method GET

Then status 200

- def txnToken = response

#print token

from above code i am getting Token's value as something like this "gdjsgjshjhsjfhsg646"

now i have another feature file where i have to use above Token's value in my query parameter value as
Feature: Testing datent Name and Client

Background:

header Content-Type 'application/json""

def endpoints read('classpath:src/test/java/com/ade/resources/endpoints.json") def CookieGenerator Java.type('com.ade.Helpers.CookiesGenerator");

- call read('Token.feature')
  Given url baseUrl+endpoints.dit.Client.path

Scenario: To check the Schema of the response

Given def head read('classpath:src/test/java/com/ade/resources/reqpay.json") =

def req head.data[1]

And cookies (new CookieGenerator().getCookieValue())

And request req

And param {txntoken = txnToken}
When method post

Then status 200

from above my endpoint should be like [https://something.com/clients?txntoken='gdjsgjshjhsjfhsg646'](https://something.com/clients?txntoken=%27gdjsgjshjhsjfhsg646%27)
but i am getting as https://something.com/clients?txntoken=txnToken

[https://something.com/clients?txntoken='gdjsgjshjhsjfhsg646'](https://something.com/clients?txntoken=%27gdjsgjshjhsjfhsg646%27)

Comment: I'm sorry this question is too complicated to understand so unless you follow this process I can't help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - hopefully someone else can. since you are new here, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Your post is hard to read, as @peter-thomas said, please try formatting it better in the future, or edit the post if I haven't answered your question.

I believe what you're looking for is described in the documentation [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-other-feature-files)

```
  * def signIn = call read('classpath:my-signin.feature') { username: 'john', password: 'secret' }
  * def authToken = signIn.authToken
```

you can see how information can be passed

I also asked a similar question fairly recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74185966/calling-a-feature-from-b-feature-is-returning-com-intuit-karate-scriptobjectmap)

relevant bit here:

```
* def key = karate.call('ReadRoundUpSubscription.feature');

* def keyvalue = key.acckey
```

i prefer to call features like this, and not defining things in the reusable feature.